# JSObject.call don't seem to work with Javascript namespaces

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jsobject

I have a Java Applet which uses some Javascript functions which are declared in an Javascript Object.

The Javascript looks like this

```
            var foo ={
            bar: function( var) {
            //do stuff
            }};
```

The Applet is loaded after the Javascript Object has been created.
The function is callable if I use the Javascript console. I use the following call

```
foo.bar.("something");
```

my Applet uses the call method of JSObject

```
    Object[] args = { "something" };
    win.call("foo.bar", args);
```

This results in an Exception.

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: No such method "foo.bar" on JavaScript object
```

if I use the eval method of JSObject to call foo.bar it works. but I don't want to use eval

Is there a way to make the call method work as expected so that I can use a Javascript object to structure my code ?

Comment: *"if I use the eval method of JSObject to call foo.bar it works. but I don't want to use eval"*  ..that seems a silly restriction.

Comment: The  eval solution gets problematic if one JS function gets user input. The user could change the syntax of evals string and execute code. To prevent this I would have to escape the input and I hope to avoid this extra work.